# find, xargs: execute chain of commands for each file

Tags: bash, shell, find, pipe, xargs

I am sorry if the question title is not informative enough. Please feel free to suggest a better variant.

I want to perform the following task:
In a directory I have a number of files that are photos in JPEG format. I want to extract from EXIF the dates when those photos were taken, create a new directory for each date, and move a file to the relevant directory.

(EXIF date and time have the format `YYYY:MM:DD hh:mm:ss`, and I want the directory names to be formatted as `YYYY-MM-DD`, that's why I use sed)

I kind of know how to perform each of those tasks separately, but failed to put them together. I spent some time investigating how to execute commands using `find` with `-exec` or `xargs` but still failed to understand how to properly chain everything.

Finally I was able to fulfil my task using two commands:

```
find . -name '*.jpg' -exec sh -c "identify -format %[exif:DateTimeOriginal] {}
    | sed 's/ [0-9:]*//; s/:/-/g' | xargs mkdir -p" \;

find . -name '*.jpg' -exec sh -c "identify -format %[exif:DateTimeOriginal] {}
    | sed 's/ [0-9:]*//; s/:/-/g; s/$/\//' | xargs mv {}" \;
```

But I do not like the duplication, and I do not like `-exec sh -c`. Is there the right way to do this in one line and without using `-exec sh -c`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather than focusing on one-liners, a better solution would be to put the logic into a script which makes it easy to execute and test.  Put this in a file called `movetodate.sh`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# This script takes one or more image file paths

set -e
set -o pipefail

for path in "$@"; do
    date=$(identify -format %[exif:DateTimeOriginal] | sed 's/ [0-9:]*//; s/:/-/g')
    dest=$(dirname "$path")/$date
    mkdir -p "$dest"
    mv "$path" "$dest"
done
```

Then, to invoke it:

```
find . -name '*.jpg' -exec ./movetodate.sh {} +
```

Answer (score 2):

It is easily done with [exiftool](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/):

```
exiftool "-Directory<DateTimeOriginal" -d %Y-%m-%d *.jpg
```

For example, the command transforms a layout like this:

```
.
├── a.jpg  (2013:10:17 10:01:00)
└── b.jpg  (2012:08:07 16:11:15)
```

to this:

```
.
├── 2012-08-07
│   └── b.jpg
└── 2013-10-17
    └── a.jpg
```

If you still want to use `identify`, the commands can be rewritten as follows:

```
script=$(cat <<'SCRIPT'
d=$(
  d=$(identify -format "%[exif:DateTimeOriginal]" "$0" 2>/dev/null) || exit $?
  d=${d:0:10}
  printf '%s/%s' "$(dirname "$0")" "${d//:/-}"
) || exit $?
mkdir -p "$d" && mv -v "$0" "$d"
SCRIPT
)

find "$dir" -name '*.jpg' -exec bash -c "$script" {} \;
```

Note the use of `$0` variable within the script. We pass the `{}` placeholder to the script as the first argument.

The script can easily be transformed to accept multiple arguments (paths) with the help of a `for file in "$@"` loop. In this case the `\;` character should be replaced with `+`. However, if you have a large number of files exceeding the `$(getconf ARG_MAX)` limit, you will need either `xargs`, or processing the files one by one as shown in the script above. The same considerations are applied to the `exiftool` command.

Answer (score 0):

With parallel you do not need the script but would instead do:

```
doit() {
  path="$1"
  date=$(identify -format %[exif:DateTimeOriginal] | sed 's/ [0-9:]*//; s/:/-/g')
  dest=$(dirname "$path")/$date
  mkdir -p "$dest"
  mv "$path" "$dest"
}
export -f doit
find . -name '*.jpg' | parallel doit
```